# Using dget to build package from mentors.debian.net

Tags: debian

I'm trying to build this package: http://mentors.debian.net/package/isbg

I thus ran:

```
dget http://mentors.debian.net/debian/pool/main/i/isbg/isbg_0.99-5.dsc
```

But the gpg verification fails:

```
dget: retrieving http://mentors.debian.net/debian/pool/main/i/isbg/isbg_0.99-5.dsc
--2014-05-21 14:52:20--  http://mentors.debian.net/debian/pool/main/i/isbg/isbg_0.99-5.dsc
Resolving mentors.debian.net (mentors.debian.net)... 185.22.221.46
Connecting to mentors.debian.net (mentors.debian.net)|185.22.221.46|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1070 (1,0K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘isbg_0.99-5.dsc’

100%[======================================>] 1 070       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-05-21 14:52:20 (179 MB/s) - ‘isbg_0.99-5.dsc’ saved [1070/1070]

dget: using existing isbg_0.99.orig.tar.bz2
dget: using existing isbg_0.99-5.debian.tar.xz
isbg_0.99-5.dsc:
dscverify: isbg_0.99-5.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: Signature made sam 19 avr 2014 05:28:51 EDT using DSA key ID 50D0AE60
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

I did download the author's gpg public key via:

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 50D0AE60
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `dscverify` checks only the official Debian keyrings. If you want to also use your personal keyring to verify signatures, place this line in `~/.devscripts`:

```
DSCVERIFY_KEYRINGS="~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg"
```